# compare two text files then update the specific values based on the matching first column. (python)

Tags: python

I have two files. File1 needs to grab values from file2 only if they have the same ID number. I only want to grab the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE values from file2. I need to update these values. I am not sure why the code below is not showing the output I want.

```
File1.txt

#ID CAT CHN LC SC LATITUDE LONGITUDE 
20022 CX 21 --   4  32.739000  -114.635700 
01711 CX 21 --   3  32.779700  -115.567500
08433 CX 21 --   2  31.919930  -123.321000


File2.txt

20022,32.45,-114.88
01192,32.839,-115.487
01711,32.88,-115.45
01218,32.717,-115.637

output
#ID CAT CHN LC SC LATITUDE LONGITUDE 
20022 CX 21 --   4  32.45  -114.88 
01711 CX 21 --   3  32.88  -115.45
08433 CX 21 --   2  31.919930  -123.321000
```

The code I have so far.

```
file1_data = []

file1_headers = []

with open("File1.txt") as file1:
    for line in file1:
        file1_data.append(line.strip().split("\n"))
    file1_headers = file1_data[0]
    del file1_data[0]

file2_data = []

with open("File2.txt") as file2:
    for line in file2:
        file2_data.append(line.strip().split("\n")) 

file2_ids = [x[0] for x in file2_data]

final_data = [file1_headers] + file1_data

for i in range(1, len(final_data)):
    if final_data[i][0] in file2_ids:
        match = [x for x in file2_data if x[0] == final_data[i][0]]
        final_data[i] = [match[0] + [final_data[i][3]]]


with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    output.writelines("\n".join(["\n".join(x) for x in final_data]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this script.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# load data:
data1, data2 = defaultdict(list), {}
with open('File1.txt', 'r') as f_in1, open('File2.txt', 'r') as f_in2:
    for line in f_in1:
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#'):
            d = line.strip().split()
            data1[d[0]].append(d)

    for line in f_in2:
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#'):
            d = line.strip().split(',')
            data2[d[0]] = d

# change data:
for k, v in data2.items():
    if k not in data1:
        continue
    for vv in data1[k]:
        vv[5] = v[1]
        vv[6] = v[2]

# write data to file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    print('#ID\tCAT\tCHN\tLC\tSC\tLATITUDE\tLONGITUDE', file=f_out)
    for d in data1.values():
        for line in d:
            print(*line, sep='\t', file=f_out)
```

Produces `output.txt`:

```
#ID CAT CHN LC  SC  LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
20022   CX  21  --  4   32.45   -114.88
01711   CX  21  --  3   32.88   -115.45
08433   CX  21  --  2   31.919930   -123.321000
```

Answer (score 0):

`line.strip().split` doesn't do what you think it does. You can see how to use it below. I also recommend using a dictionary in cases like this where you have a clear key and values for efficiency. I split the original file by spaces to maintain structure when joining later, and removed some redundant intermediate variables as well.

In general, I would recommend against relying so heavily on format, since an extra space could ruin everything. Consider creating a class for the objects described by each line for more modularity.

```
with open("File1.txt") as file1:
    output_data = [(line.strip().split(' ')) for line in file1]

with open("File2.txt") as file2:
    file2_data = [line.strip().split(",") for line in file2]

# save the latitude and longitude.
file2_data = {x[0]: (x[1], x[2]) for x in file2_data}

# replace the output in the original data
for i in range(1, len(output_data)):
    id = output_data[i][0]
    if id in file2_data:
        output_data[i][8] = file2_data[id][0]
        output_data[i][10] = file2_data[id][1]


with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    output.writelines("\n".join([" ".join(i) for i in output_data]))
```

This produces the output:

```
#ID CAT CHN LC SC LATITUDE LONGITUDE
20022 CX 21 --   4  32.45  -114.88
01711 CX 21 --   3  32.88  -115.45
08433 CX 21 --   2  31.919930  -123.321000
```

Comment: I tried that, but nothing changed. The values are not changing.